# SDL3 CMake linkage problem undefined reference for SDL

Tags: c++, cmake, cygwin, sdl, undefined-reference

When trying to link **SDL3** as **git submodule** I get many errors:

```
...
undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer'
...
```

What am I missing?

Here is my **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)

project(project VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_subdirectory(extern/sdl)
include_directories(Inc)

add_executable(project Src/main.cpp)

target_include_directories(project PUBLIC extern/sdl/include)
target_link_directories(project PUBLIC SDL3::SDL3)
```

**I'm using:**

- **Windows 11** (But I'd like it to be compileable on any platform - Unix was easy for me to setup. Windows is causing problems)
- **gcc 11.4** (Cygwin)
- **SDL3** - I take main branch, but SDL2 or basically any other release was the same
- **CLion** as the IDE (idk if that makes any difference)

**UPDATE**

After adding:

```
target_link_libraries(project PRIVATE SDL3::SDL3)
```

I get an error:

```
SDL_hidapi_windows.h:57:30: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'SDL_toupper_REAL'
57 | #define towupper    (wchar_t)SDL_toupper
```

Comment: Missing `target_link_libraries` to actually link with the libraries?

Comment: Hmm yeah, added that, but that creates another problem (I updated the question)
For some reason I forgot this one. I recall it might be a problem with a compiler, but what can I do about that? I didn't want to change it as I'd like it to be easily-compiled. Also couldn't find the one that would fix my problem :/

Comment: Builds fine for me with [`target_link_libraries(project SDL3::SDL3)`](https://pastebin.com/DL2EqXZU), [tips of `main`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/commit/bb4ec5250f550b81c12e3661169b3ab65ad699a6), and & VS2022.

Comment: what compiler did You use? What are Your CMake settings?

Comment: ***SDL_hidapi_windows.h:57:30: error: expected*** We probably need to see more context on that header to understand why this error happens in cygwin. In any case I think that part is off-topic to the original question.

Comment: Commenting out this line helped, but not for long
There also have been an error for not matching declaration of a `SDL_SYS_CreateThread`, so I fixed that. Now I'm getting yet another errors with `undefined reference` I'll maybe try switching to visual studio and use it's pre installed compilers. Such lib should not be that hard to compile in my opinion.

Comment: SDL2 should be easy with msys2: [https://packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-SDL2](https://packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-SDL2)

Comment: I wanted to build it from source
The idea waas to provide submodule of required libraries aandd build it from source
that way project is not bounded to specific system and does not require anything apart from compiler
But I give up it's not worth it. I'm switching to unix as there is no problem there and remove windows from supported operating systems

Comment: there is no SDL3 package on Cygwin https://cygwin.com/packages/src_package_list.html. Are you trying to mix Cygwin and Windows build ? It can NOT work

Comment: as I said before
I was trying to compile SDL from source on Windows